# Wrong Route in RouteGroup Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I defined some RoteGroup in api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'galleries'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'GalleriesController@index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'GalleriesController@show');
    Route::post('/', 'GalleriesController@store');
    Route::post('/{id}', 'GalleriesController@update');
    Route::delete('/{id}', 'GalleriesController@delete');
});

Route::group(['prefex'=>'files'],function(){
    Route::get('/', 'FilesController@index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'FilesController@show');
    Route::post('/', 'FilesController@store');
    Route::delete('/{id}', 'FilesController@delete');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'brands'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'BrandsController@index');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'BrandsController@show');
    Route::post('/', 'BrandsController@store');
    Route::post('/{id}', 'BrandsController@update');
    Route::delete('/{id}', 'BrandsController@delete');
});
```

when I call `/api/brands` Laravel itself calls `/api/files/{id}` and passes brands as id parameter. I cleared route cache and application cache but it doesn't works.

my `route:list` command is as follow:

```
    +--------+----------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                | Name                        | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | api                | generated::t71BZCrrwrUEipSw | App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@index      | api        |
|        | POST     | api                | generated::aShgozBu0aAJb5Oh | App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@store      | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/brands         | generated::3aUm0HLF9QQRczyA | App\Http\Controllers\BrandsController@index     | api        |
|        | POST     | api/brands         | generated::V58YTIOhzv62STxe | App\Http\Controllers\BrandsController@store     | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/brands/{id}    | generated::SuOaq2tKeDBAWcKH | App\Http\Controllers\BrandsController@show      | api        |
|        | POST     | api/brands/{id}    | generated::Ij9a3h9rjPTJtrl6 | App\Http\Controllers\BrandsController@update    | api        |
|        | DELETE   | api/brands/{id}    | generated::h9fZYI1jripojkLm | App\Http\Controllers\BrandsController@delete    | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/galleries      | generated::UGeFE22cHyQVcjCS | App\Http\Controllers\GalleriesController@index  | api        |
|        | POST     | api/galleries      | generated::oKqS94qAO9isKmCs | App\Http\Controllers\GalleriesController@store  | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/galleries/{id} | generated::mtUddNdRZr9olMHb | App\Http\Controllers\GalleriesController@show   | api        |
|        | POST     | api/galleries/{id} | generated::DD3hLUdSswKYlXse | App\Http\Controllers\GalleriesController@update | api        |
|        | DELETE   | api/galleries/{id} | generated::QTxRv04TlN24QgWO | App\Http\Controllers\GalleriesController@delete | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/{id}           | generated::kt66p66Ao0pBlENo | App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@show       | api        |
|        | DELETE   | api/{id}           | generated::9C7SNWSa1JbTtS1p | App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@delete     | api        |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: i think laravel is confused change your show method route to something like `/show/{id}`. Either that or something is wrong with the way your app is calling api, try using postman and see if it works

Comment: Assuming you're talking about `GET` it states `App\Http\Controllers\BrandsController@index` for `api/brands`. What makes you think it actually calls `/api/files/{id}` which has no route at all?

Comment: I use postman for calling apis. and why laravel uses /api/files for calling root api (/api)?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 because I use break point in VSCode and trace that.

Comment: @rasoulmohammadi take a look on OMR answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your route definitions. Here:

```
Route::group(['prefex'=>'files'],function(){
 [...]
});
```

Change it from 'prefex' to 'prefix':

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'files'],function(){
 [...]
});
```